# MouseLeave Event on Safari Mac is triggered under wrong conditions

Tags: javascript, safari, mouseleave

according to

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

mouseleave is fired when the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants.

However, on Safari this event is fired as soon the mouse enters the element and is moved inside of it. I created a fiddle

```js
document.getElementById('out').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => console.log('left'));
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="out">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hs5ea7cq/

```
document.getElementById('out').addEventListener('mouseleave', () => console.log('left'));
```

On Chrome, FireFox on Mac it works as it should. However, Safari emits mouseleave even so it should not.

Is there anything I can do to get the same behavior in Safari as in Chrome or FireFox?

EDIT:

I created a GIF which shows the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8j0F.jpg

Comment: Safari seems to be becoming the new IE...

Comment: I can't replicate the issue? The log only fires in safari when the user's mouse leaves the green square. This is the same as Firefox and Chrome on macOS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Thanks for trying. I created a video of the issue and linked it in the description. What Mac version you are on? What Safar version are you using?

Comment: Safari 15.4 on macOS 12.3.1 https://imgur.com/a/27ZkXjf

Comment: Can't replicate it on Safari 15.2, macOS 11.6.4 either. What versions are you on @bugAtron9000?

Comment: I am using Mac 12.1.0 and Safari 15.2. I also use VNC to remote into the machine. Might this cause issues with Safari?

Comment: @ChrisG it seems like that's not the case.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I keep seeing questions on here about something working everywhere except Safari. In fact, Safari has been the new IE for some time now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to TigerVNC usage. Switching to UltraVNC resolved the issue.